# Android Studio - Stuck on "Build Gradle" when creating a new project

Tags: windows, android-studio, gradle

I have tried different solutions but none of them seem to work for me.
I have installed the latest AS on my Windows 7.
Everything downloaded fine(I'm not behind any proxy)
However, when I try to create a new Project, after I set the name,Activity name(which I live as default) and finish the settings, a message pops up saying "Gradle Build";
It keeps building but I don't know what it's doing.

I've tried the following steps to fix it:
-Deleted .gradle so that it creates a fresh one as the original might be corrupted
-Downloaded gradle manually and pointed AS to this
-Downloaded gradle zip manually and put it in .gradle>wrapper>dists>2.14.1>***numbers***>zip file here

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

1) Install gradle as command line tool https://gradle.org/install

2) Type "gradle -v" in command line. Mine gave issues with hava SDK, so I had to install new java SDK and change JAVA_HOME path variable

3) Start creating new project

4) Navigate to new project location, open command line and type "grade build"
It gave me this error "Warning: License for package Android Support Repository not accepted."

```
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
[Android Support Repository].
Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and    
complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK 
Manager. Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation 
to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

5) Launch SDK manager with Administrator privileges (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk)

6) Install selected packages. In my case based on error I had to install an additional package "Android Support Repository" too

7) Build project using command line to ensure no further errors. Run "gradle build"

8) Launch Android Studio with administrator privileges

It will work from Android Studio too now

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same probleme, i had to wait a long time, but then it was working, may be waiting is a solution (ac)

Comment: I left my laptop all night and in the morning it was still building gradle. On the mac it takes less than 3 minutes. My windows 7 laptop it's a good performance laptop and internet connection is good.

Comment: have you already built an other application using your AS, is it  the first time that you are doing this?

Comment: have you properly installed an android sdk, what  is the default SDK version  that you are using to build your app

Comment: The sdk was automatically downloaded by Android Studio and I remember it saying that it's the latest version. I had an SDK installed previously as well but I didn't do anything with the SDK when installing Android Studio as AS was handling the installation of the SDK itself.

Comment: android sdk tools 25.2.2

Comment: any idea guys, really need this working. I've unistalled everything and installed android studio again, still the same issue.